# User Defined Scalar functions in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and am learning User Defined Functions in SQL

I have two tables and I have given the rows I have inserted to those tables.

```
--Table1

create table sql_exam(
exa_examid bigint not null primary key,
exa_name varchar(100) not null,
exa_maxmark decimal(5,2) not null,
exa_minmarkreqdforpass decimal(5,2) not null,
exa_examscheduletime datetime not null
)

--Rows inserted into Table1

insert into sql_exam(exa_examid,exa_name,exa_maxmark,exa_minmarkreqdforpass,exa_examscheduletime) values (1,'Maths',100,40,'2012-10-10 10:00')
insert into sql_exam(exa_examid,exa_name,exa_maxmark,exa_minmarkreqdforpass,exa_examscheduletime) values (2,'English',75,35,'2012-10-11 10:00')

--Table2

create table sql_studentmarks(
stm_studentid int not null primary key,
stm_examid bigint foreign key references sql_exam(exa_examid),
stm_mark decimal(5,2)
)

--Rows inserted into Table2
insert into sql_studentmarks(stm_studentid,stm_examid,stm_mark) values (1,1,80)
insert into sql_studentmarks(stm_studentid,stm_examid,stm_mark) values (2,1,90)
insert into sql_studentmarks(stm_studentid,stm_examid,stm_mark) values (3,1,40)
insert into sql_studentmarks(stm_studentid,stm_examid,stm_mark) values (1,2,70)
insert into sql_studentmarks(stm_studentid,stm_examid,stm_mark) values (2,2,60)
insert into sql_studentmarks(stm_studentid,stm_examid,stm_mark) values (3,2,17)
```

I require a help about creating Scalar functions and I need to get

1. A scalar function which will return the Student ID of the student who got highest mark in 'Maths'
2. A tabular function which will return the student ID and marks gained by the student who got highest total mark.

Am just trying to learn SQL. I have tried - "

```
create function fnGetMathsHightest()
returns int
as
begin
declare @st_id int
return @st_id
end



select dbo.fnGetMathsHightest() 
from sql_studentmarks 
where stm_examid=1 
group by stm_studentid 
having stm_mark=max(stm_mark)
```

for the first one. It does not look good.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, I was not able to comment it here, so I edited my question there.

Comment: Actually am just a beginner. And I thought if we specify the exam id (1 for maths) in the where clause it should work.

Comment: Ok. Can you display only those marks for 'Math' sorted descending by mark ?

Comment: Are you pointing to this query - "select stm_studentid from sql_studentmarks where stm_examid=1 order by stm_mark desc" @BogdanSahlean

Comment: Now, the first row has the highest mark. You can filter only the first row by using [TOP (1)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx).

Comment: okay... but how to do it using a scalar function? (say fnGetMathsHightest()..) @BogdanSahlean

Comment: Bellow, there is Co. Aden's answer which contains a scalar function. You could change that scalar function to call your query. A scalar function may return only one value (ex. a value from `stm_studentid ` column). And you should use `SET @vID = (subquery)` instead of `SET @vID = subquery`.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean And for the second one, i tried "create function fnGetHighestTotalMarks
returns table(studentid int,mark decimal(5,2))
as
return (select stm_studentid,stm_mark from sql_studentmarks where sum(stm_mark)=max(sum(stm_mark))
end" It is also not working. Please guide me.

Comment: First, I would try to compute the total of `std_mark` for every `stm_studentid`. Then I would try to use the same technique (sorting descending by totals + TOP(1)).

Comment: Note: In both cases, you could have not just one student but more students having the same maximum `std_mark` or total of `std_mark`. In this case, it's better to use TOP(1) WITH TIES. Also, in this case, you can't use a scalar function for query #1 (use instead a inline tabular function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this what you want  for 1.

```
CREATE FUNCTION ssfnGetStudenytId
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

declare @vId as int 
set @vId =  Select stm_studentid  from  sql_studentmarks where stm_mark = (SELECT  MAX( stm_mark )from sql_studentmarks )

RETURN @vId
END
```

Comment: Hi Co. Aden, my 'sql_exam' table contains two exam subjects. Maths and English. And 'sql_studentmarks' contain the studentID and marks obtained by each student for each subject. The scalar function should return the ID of the student who got the highest in Maths.